# WFFM Drop List strips symbols from manually entered options

Tags: wffm

Using Sitecore 8.2. I have a number of WFFM forms. On one of my forms, I've added a droplist with manually entered options. The last option is supposed to have a plus sign, e.g. "50,000+". However when I click OK, the plus signs are stripped from the Value and Text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround look for drop-list field you added in Sitecore content tree, look for a field called "Localized Parameters", you will find the manually entered values there, search for **25000+** and replace it with **25000%2B**. it looks like the + is encoded into space.

**Make sure to test this on testing enviroment first, A-Z, display, submission, and reports.**